# Linear span of two non-intersecting lines in projective space

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

If i have 2 lines, say $L$ and $M$ in the projective space $\Bbb P^4$. It is given that they don't intersect.
Is  $\left<L,M\right>$ the smallest subspace of $\Bbb P^4$ to contain them both? Just like in affine geometry?
So in this case $\left<L,M\right>$ would be a plane of $2$ dimensions?

Comment: Note that any $4$ points of a projective space cannot span more than a $3$-dimensional projective subspace. Since $L$ and $M$ are each spanned by a pair of points, they cannot avoid being in some ($3$-dimensional) hyperplane here, so that hypothesis is absurd.

Comment: It was a question in my textbook, so I just copied the information I got for the question to here.

Comment: Well if your textbook asks a question with an absurd hypothesis, you could just point that out and conclude there is nothing left to prove (since the hypothesis cannot be met).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The span of $L, M$ will be a hyperplane (dimension $3$) in $\mathbb{P}^4$. This can be seen by looking at the corresponding vector space $V$ of $\mathbb{P}^4$ of dimension $5$. The lines $L, M$ correspond to $2$-dimensional subspaces of $V$ which intersect trivially. The span of the subspaces induced by $L, M$ then is a $4$-dimensional subspace of $V$ since $L \cap M = \{0\}$ by assumption. Therefore, the span of $L, M$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{P}^4$ of dimension $3$.

**Note:** I have ignored the assumption that $L, M$ are not contained in the same hyperplane since this is the case as showed.

Comment: In a vector space, subspaces that "do not intersect" don't really exist; that should be "intersect trivially" or "form a direct sum". Also, as in the question, I think "linear" should be dropped when talking about subspaces of a projective space (such subspaces are assumed to contain the with every pair of points the entire line connecting them).

Comment: You're completely right. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Does the last line of the first paragraph mean that the span of L,M is a projective subspace of $\mathbb{P}^4$ of projective dimension 3?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.